# How to get back Java Preferences in OS X with Java for OS X 2012-006?

Tags: java, applet, osx-mountain-lion, java-web-start, java-6

After installing the [Java for OS X 2012-006](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) update, the Java Preferences app, for configuring applets and, more importantly for me, Java Web Start apps has gone. The [tech note](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5493) about this update says:

> This update also removes the Java Preferences application, which is no longer required to configure applet settings.

If it's no longer required, what has replaced it, or how do I get back the same functionality?
One of the things I used to be able to do was configure when / how the Java Console appeared. Now it doesn't appear ever, and there's apparently nothing I can do about it!

I already followed the steps in [this tech note](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559) in order to re-enable the the Java plugin and Web Start functionality, even though I hadn't ever installed a Java 7 JRE.

I'm running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2.

Comment: Configure what exactly?  Recently JREs allow for the a lot to be configured in the applet parameters themselves.  JWS apps. always had considerable control over the run-time environment used to launch them.

Comment: @AndrewThompson well, configure if the Java Console launches for any applet or JWS app, or only if there's an error, for example. Apart from that, the Preferences app lets you manage the cache of JWS apps, which I mostly used for wiping everything to solve unexplained weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read [this CNET article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57533880-263/java-preferences-missing-after-latest-os-x-java-update/) which appears to indicate that the Apple now expects you install a Java 7 JRE from Oracle to get back applet and JWS support. The Oracle Java 7 JRE has its own preferences app.

The other option is to bring back the Apple Java Preferences app from a Time Machine backup, if it's available.

So, in summary the answer is one of:

- install a Java 7 JRE from Oracle.
- get a copy of the old Apple preferences app from a backup.

Answer (score 3):

After I have installed `jdk-7u10-macosx-x64.dmg` on `Mac OS X Moutain Lion`. It is the JDK 7 update 10 Developer Preview Release.

I've got this :

[image: system preferences]

Comment: Yep, that confirms what I said in my own answer, which is that you have to use a Java 7 JRE / JDK. There's no way to get back the Apple Java 6 Preferences app, unless you have a copy on a backup.

Answer (score 0):

The Java configuration panel is now with the System Preferences.