# Android Studio IDE with private jre/jdk? OSX

Tags: android, macos, java, android-studio

I'm running OSX 10.8 and was trying to run the Android Studio app bundle using a private jdk rather than one that is globally installed.

EDIT:  I don't have any java installation globally accessible.

I have done this successfully in the past with Eclipse by editing the plist.info file and specifying what JRE/JDK I want to use via the eclipse.ini file.

I haven't found the magic on how to do this with Android Studio.

After editing the plist file unsuccessfully I opened a terminal and added the JDK/bin directory to the PATH and set a JAVA_HOME but that wasn't enough for the idea_applauncher to find a Java installation where I had specified.

I'm not sure what else I could try to make this happen.  Any ideas?

EDIT:
I don't have enough rep to post a screenshot, but below that what the command-line looks like with the output.

When I try to run the bundle I get a pop-up window saying there's no JDK installed and it has two buttons asking me to either "Install" or "Not Now"

> $ ./idea_appLauncher
>
> > No Java runtime present, requesting install.

Comment: I'm not too sure how this works on OSX but have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10655929/1449972) answer?

Comment: I appreciate the link, I don't think that will work because that answer is just solving a search priority problem.  My problem is that I don't have any JRE/JDK installed on my Mac (by design).

I need to figure out how to bypass the "Is java installed check" and point the studio to the JDK I have on disk.

Comment: How about adding a screenshot to your question to clarify where you are stuck? Is [this](http://i.imgur.com/g3bRZtn.png) your 'error'?

Comment: This was added to the support page and has been assigned someone to look at it.  It works on Windows, so hopefully they'll add the same for Mac.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55448

Comment: Take a look here: http://spsneo.com/blog/2014/07/06/android-studio-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 9):

Another solution for OSX: go to the Applications folder, right click on Android Studio, choose "Show Package Contents".

Open the Info.plist file. Locate the JVMVersion key, and set the string value you need.

In my case, I needed to be 1.7 and up to be able to run the RoboVM plugin, and the value was **1.6*,1.7+**, so I left it only on 1.7+.

Restart Android Studio and it should be using the version of the JVM you need.

This works if you have root access on your Mac.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ export STUDIO_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk
$ open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

[here is explain link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk)

Comment: While this link may have detailed information about the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I just check the executable script that starts android-studio, if you are arleady familiar with intellijIdea it is the same.

```
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Locate a JDK installation directory which will be used to run the IDE.
  # Try (in order): STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, "java" in PATH.
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  if [ -n "$STUDIO_JDK" -a -x "$STUDIO_JDK/bin/java" ]; then
    JDK="$STUDIO_JDK"
  elif [ -n "$JDK_HOME" -a -x "$JDK_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
    JDK="$JDK_HOME"
  elif [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" -a -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
    JDK="$JAVA_HOME"
  else
    JAVA_BIN_PATH=`which java`
    if [ -n "$JAVA_BIN_PATH" ]; then
      if [ "$OS_TYPE" = "FreeBSD" -o "$OS_TYPE" = "MidnightBSD" ]; then
        JAVA_LOCATION=`JAVAVM_DRYRUN=yes java | "$GREP" '^JAVA_HOME' | "$CUT" -c11-`
```

As written in the comments of the bash scripts, just add a **STUDIO_JDK** environment variable with the absolute path of the desired JDK.

This is my ideaj.sh bash script which i stored in /etc/profile.d

```
export IDEA_JDK=/opt/jdk1.7.0_71
export STUDIO_JDK=/opt/jdk1.7.0_71
```

Add to /etc/bash.bashrc to automatically set the variables at every login.

```
source /opt/profile.d/ideaj.sh
```

All this should be applied to linux, on OS X can be a little different, but the theory is the same.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the app to start:

In spotlight see if you have a "java preferences".
From there you can add you own jdk/jre and let it be the one used by osx.
If you dont have it,  you will need to install a java jre as in this question :
[How to get back Java Preferences in OS X with Java for OS X 2012-006?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289147/how-to-get-back-java-preferences-in-os-x-with-java-for-os-x-2012-006)

Then you should be able to get the "java preferences" app and add your custom jdk there

This should help you get started with project related sdk stuff.

1. Open your project with modules
2. select a module in the project pane
3. right click > " open module settings"
4. select SDKs on the modal that appears
5. click the + icon (middle content area on the top)
6. select jdk
7. target the folder "to the JDK [you] have on disk"
8. hit choose

Comment: I appreciate it, but I can't get that far.  Without Java installed globally the program never executes so as near as I can tell I'm not at a point where I could set any module specific settings.

Comment: When java preferences comes up in Spotlight I get the same "To open "Java Preferences.app" you need a java SE 6 runtime.  Would you like to install one now?"

Comment: Yea. go for it. Install, then use it to config osx to you use custom one (by path) by default.

Comment: Trying to avoid having Java available to all applications on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable; ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK and use it for the path to your JDK.

source: http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1ee2ea/google_announces_android_studio_a_new_development/c9zfklt

Comment: Set ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK to
> /<path>/dev/jdk  (the absolute path to the JDK)


Didn't seem to change the behavior.  Thanks for the link though.