# robovm plugin don't start on Android Studio intellij and el capitan 10.11.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, robovm

when i start android studio with robovm plugin initialized, i see this error:

```
Plugin 'org.robovm.intellij' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please restart Android Studio.

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: org/robovm/idea/components/RoboVmApplicationComponent : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 [Plugin: org.robovm.intellij]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:130)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.tryLoadingClass(PluginClassLoader.java:77)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentsRegistry.loadClasses(ComponentManagerImpl.java:427)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentsRegistry.loadClasses(ComponentManagerImpl.java:417)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentsRegistry.access$000(ComponentManagerImpl.java:403)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:499)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:481)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:170)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/robovm/idea/components/RoboVmApplicationComponent : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:471)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:259)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:255)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:231)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:124)
    ... 30 more
```

how to solve this error ? 
i have see online but i don't find any solution for my specified error

i use Android Studio 1.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force Android Studio to use a JVM version 1.7 or higher. By default, it uses version 1.6

[Here are some ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593729/android-studio-ide-with-private-jre-jdk-osx/33339069#33339069) , depending on the OS you use.