# Android Studio and JRE on OS X

Tags: java, android-studio, osx-elcapitan

Installing AndroidStudio 2.0 on OS X El Capitan: if I install JRE 7 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html, I will not receive Public Updates; if I install JRE 8, Android Studio complains that it cannot use secure connection to receive upgrades:

[image: Android Studio and Java screenshot]

Is there a way to convince AS that JRE 8 is not JRE 6? If impossible, which compromise is preferable: downgrade to JRE 7 and establish secure connection for Android Studio upgrades, or keep the latest JRE and wait for Android Studio fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation, by default Android Studio is launched from java 6: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk

As it is mentioned you can export an env variable to indicate Android Studio what jdk to use :

```
export STUDIO_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk
```

In order to keep this env variable accessible from the GUI, you can add the following line to your ~/.profile file :

```
launchctl setenv STUDIO_JDK /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes! I didn't notice that JDK 1.6 was installed on my computer. Deleting it fixed the problem (*or maybe upgraded AS, 2.1.1, recognized JDK 8?*)

Comment: Same with AS 2.1.1. You still have to do the STUDIO_JDK trick or removing all the other jdk as you did ;)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for OSX: go to the Applications folder, right click on Android Studio, choose "Show Package Contents".

Open the Info.plist file. Locate the JVMVersion key, and set the string value you need.

In my case, I needed to be 1.7 and up to be able to run the RoboVM plugin, and the value was 1.6*,1.7+, so I left it only on 1.7+.

Restart Android Studio and it should be using the version of the JVM you need.

This works if you have root access on your Mac.

### refers to [Android Studio IDE with private jre/jdk? OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593729/android-studio-ide-with-private-jre-jdk-osx)

---

In Android Studio 2.1.2 and below,the default settings is '1.6*,1.7+'.

In the latest version of Android Studio(2.2 Preview 7),the default settings is '1.8*,1.8+'.